# VBA search values in column and highlight matches in range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some trouble finding a way to highlight values in a range when that value exists in a certain column.

Column `O` has formulas which may populate values. Each of those values has it's own column starting in `R`. `O10` could say "OD". Column `S` has a column Header in `S8` that says "OD". Most of the cells below it are blank, but if they are not, they will say "OD", so since "OD" is found in Column `O`, I want All values not blank in column `S` to be .style = "Neutral".

Relevant Range for `O` needs to be `O8` thru the last row. Columns to search for those values in will be `R8:Last Column`.

I have a decent start. I can get it to hightlight any non-blank values the way I want, but I can't get it to also make sure that value is in column `O` before it changes the style.

here's the code so far:

```
Sub HighlightCompGrid()

Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long, x As Long, c As Range
Dim Selected As Range
Dim Grid As Range

FirstRow = Range("B:B").Find("ID", Range("B1")).Row
LastRow = Range("B:B").Find("End", Range("B8")).Row
i = Range("B" & FirstRow & ":B" & LastRow).Count

Set Grid = Range("R9", Range("R9").Offset(i - 1, i - 1))
Set Selected = Range("O9", Range("O9").Offset(i - 1, 0))

Selected.Select

For Each c In Grid
    If c.Value = Selected.Value Then
        Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Style = "Neutral"
    Else 'Do Nothing
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't compare a cell with a whole range like that. You could use Find again, or Match and check if it's a number. When using Find it's good practice to assign a range object and check if nothing as your code will error if "ID" or "End" are not found. You might also want to read up on Resize rather than Offset (no great shakes though).

Comment: May I take a look of your data? So that I can edit the code correctly.

Comment: you mean post the file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a macro for this. You can use an Excel feature called *Conditional Formatting*.

## Conditional Formatting

Simply select your desired column in the worksheet, in the Ribbon go to `Home -> Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cells Rules -> Equal To...`

As you can't just have nothing in the formula, just enter anything. Then alter the newly created rule by clicking `Home -> Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules`

There, change it so that the rule is `=""`

## Macro

If you really need a macro though, here's how I would do it:

```
Sub styleEmptyCells()

    Const FIRST_ROW        as Long = 2
    Const COLUMN_TO_CHECK  as String = "O"

    Dim i                  as Long 
    Dim lastrow            as Long

    lastrow = Range("A65535").End(xlUp).row

    For i = FIRST_ROW to lastrow
        If Range(COLUMN_TO_CHECK & i) = "" Then
           Range(COLUMN_TO_CHECK & i).Style = "Neutral" 
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Conditional formatting would be easier, but i won't bore you with the story as to why I can't use it in this range... I'm not wanting to highlight blank cells. I want to highlight the values in a range of columns, but only when those values also exist in column O. Let's say Column V is for "Fork". Out of the 100+ rows in that column, they're either going to be blank, or they're going to say "Fork". I don't want them to be highlighted unless "Fork" is also found in Column O. So, If O12's formula returns "Fork", then all of the non-blank values in Column V will be highlighted.

Comment: So basically something like: `If Range("O" & i) = "Fork" And Range("V" & i) = "Fork" Then Range("V" & i).Style = "Neutral"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found some code online that I was able to modify to suit my need. It is SO SIMPLE in comparison to the crazy hoops I was trying to get through.

Here's what the code wound up looking like

```
Sub HighlightCompGrid()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

TransposeNames
FillDownFormats
'these two macros will "reset" the grid

Dim FirstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, i As Long, c As Range
Dim Selected As Range
Dim Grid As Range

FirstRow = Range("B:B").Find("ID", Range("B1")).Row
lastRow = Range("B:B").Find("End", Range("B8")).Row
i = Range("B" & FirstRow & ":B" & lastRow).Count

Set Grid = Range("R9", Range("R9").Offset(i - 1, i - 1))
Set Selected = Range("O9", Range("O9").Offset(i - 1, 0))

For Each c In Grid
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(c, Selected, 0)) Then
        c.Style = "Neutral"
        c.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End If
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

It loops through each value in `Column O` and checks for matches in my range of columns (Grid) and when they do... enter commands.